Proof of this derivative definition for polynomials in a finite field polynomial ring? $f(x)=q(x)(x-\alpha)^2+f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)+\beta$
There is a protocol in a cryptographic paper that uses a definition for a polynomial derivative that I believe is right; but I can't use it until I am sure it is.

Can anybody give me a proper explanation for this, or point to an academic resource, so that I can introduce this definition in a paper? I've been searching for a while, and whilst I recognise this is most likely the Taylor expansion in the finite field setting, saying that is not enough.
My intuition is that, obviously $\beta=f(\alpha),$ and that $q(x)$ wraps all the higher order derivatives into a single term (allowed since they should all be multiplied by $(x-\alpha)$ with multiplicity at least 2).
I found these 2 resources that touch on it, but they don't have this definition precisely:

http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ag/lec05.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.07502


I think that $h$ is not unique. Take $h$ as a derivative, then $t_k(x):=h(x)+(x^p-x)^k$ for any $k$ is also a derivative.

Ok, first of all, I don't like how they define it because it is kinda confusing.
First note that the set $B_{\alpha}=\{(x-\alpha)^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_q$. Write the polynomial $f$ as a linear combination of elements in $B_{\alpha}$, i.e. $$f(x)=\sum a_i(f,\alpha)(x-\alpha)^i.$$
Note that the map $\alpha\mapsto a_1(f,\alpha)$ is the map induced by the "derivative" as in the definition you gave us.
However, as I stated in the comments, since $h$ is given as a mapping over finite fields there is no unique polynomial representing it, but a unique polynomial of degree $<q$.
Maybe one can show that the derivative how its usually defined, namely if $f(x)=\sum a_ix^i$ then $f'(x)=\sum_{i>0} ia_ix^{i-1}$, actually coincides with the polynomial they call derivative.
Edit: As @Jyrki Lahtonen rightly pointed out, $\alpha$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ in the definition. However, then there is no derivative at all for any $f$ of degree greater equal 1 because take $\alpha=x$, then $$q(x)\cdot(x-\alpha)^2+h(\alpha)(x-\alpha)+\beta=\beta\in\mathbb{F}_p.$$ So I guess its just a typo and they actually meant $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_p$.
Comment: I know of the difference between maps and polynomials over finite fields. The reason why my explanation is still valid is that they say: "the derivative of a polynomial is the unique polynomial with the property that it maps onto certain things" which is not correct. Maybe at the beginning of the paper they say something along the lines of " We always consider maps as polynomials of degree less than $q$" and then its fine but for me there is some context missing here.

Oh wow, I had also glossed over the fact that $\alpha$ is not necessarily a scalar in the definition.

Oh, its a polynomial :D Rookie mistake by me then

That is a bit strange actually. I assumed that $\alpha$ could be anything in an algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F}_p$, when there are infinitely many choices for it. That already determines the polynomial $h$ uniquely.

By the binomial theorems one gets the Horner-Ruffini formula (that they used, not invented) for long division of a polynomial by a linear factor
$$
f(X)=f(\alpha)+g(X,\alpha)(X-\alpha)
$$
$g$ is a polynomial in two variables.
Now repeat that construction for $g(X,\alpha)$ as polynomial in $X$,
$$
g(X,\alpha)=g(\alpha,\alpha)+r(X,\alpha,\alpha)(X-\alpha)
$$
and insert to get a formula similar to the claim:
$$
f(X)=f(\alpha)+g(\alpha,\alpha)(X-\alpha)+r(X,\alpha,\alpha)(X-\alpha)^2.
$$
Note that all computations are in ring operations, no division or algebraic operation required. Thus $g$ and $r$ are polynomials with coefficients in the ground ring (or field) of the original polynomial.

Does this say anything about $g(\alpha,\alpha)$ being the derivative though?

See Weierstraß decomposition formula or any other general (multi-variable) definition of the derivative. Or the algebraic equivalent (without limits) for the current case where the ground field is not the real numbers.

I spent some time on this and think I finally figured it out; I think a direct attack leads us there (though $\alpha$ should be a scalar, not in the polynomial ring).
In the finite field polynomial ring setting, it is still possible to inspect a Taylor series. The series of $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ around a scalar $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_p$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
    f(x)&=f(\alpha) + \frac{f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)}{1!} + \frac{f^{[2]}(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{f^{[n]}(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^n}{n!} \\
    &= f(\alpha) + f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha) + q(\alpha)(x-\alpha)^2,
\end{align*}
for some polynomial $q(x)$ of degree at most $n-2$. The derivative $f'(\alpha)$ is not the only polynomial that satisfies this equation, but it is the unique one that satisfies it for all $\alpha.$ So if we commit to $f'(x)$, select $\alpha$ and then show that $f'(\alpha)$ is both from the same polynomial commitment and satisfies the relation, then by the Schwartz-Zippel lemma, we can safely conclude that $f'(x)$ is indeed the derivative.
If there are any issues with this reasoning please let me know.

What about the case where $f$ is of degree more than $p$? Don't you divide by zero in the first equation?

You're right - we should bound $f(x)$ as being of degree less than $p$ (in practice in these schemes the degree is actually bounded by some $t$ that is much less than $p$ anyhow, where $t$ is the maximum c.alculated power from a trusted setup ceremony). But I guess with this degree bound we are fine?
